# Number of states and symbols in multi class Hidden Markov Model classifier

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model, multi-class

I'm designing a multi class classifier (for 4 classes) using **Discrete HMMs with States N and Symbols M** for each of the HMM.

However, I found that recognition performance(i.e highest log likelihood) of a specific class depends upon the **N and M** with which it was trained.

Most of the literature I found on the web suggests **use of same of number of states, symbols across all the HMMs**.

**I was wondering if it need not be so?** i.e. HMM1 can have 4 states, 18 symbols and HMM2 can have 5 states, 20 symbols............